# Why Do I Need To Include External jQuery Lib In WordPress For inline JS?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am -very- puzzled as to how jQuery works in Wordpress. I'm sorry if I ramble---hard to ask in a concise way. I think there is a 'deep concept' here that I want to get sorted once and for all.

If I create a simple jQuery based plug-in, the code executes just fine, using the jQuery lib which is automatically loaded with WordPress, so long as I use it in noconflict mode or even just jQuery instead of $.

BUT if I create a php template for a given theme, I cannot use jQuery at all on that php page. Just will not 'fire'. I assume it's because the js comes after WP_Header.

BUT........ if I enqueue jQuery.1.3.2 on that page, I then magically -can- not only use jQuery on that page, but the $ syntax as well.

So my question is: How come?

EDIT: Go to http://burtengineering.com/contact-us

If you look @ the source, I have an included jquery1.3.2 which is ONLY to allow the inline js to fire.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('body').prepend('<div id="popup"><h4>Processing</h4><div id="inner"><p>One moment, please.</p></div></div>');
});
</script>
```

If I don't include that script, that js will not work, even though there is the jquery 1.7 which WordPress already contains.

So again, my question is: what am I doing wrong that prevents the inline js to work. And ALSO, why can't I use the $ with my jQuery unless I include that jquery 1.3.2?

Thanks,

I don't see an Add Comment button for some reason.

---JC

Comment: what does the `console` say when you use WP's own jquery and your inline scripts or "fired"? do you get an error?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. I try inserting a breakpoint on the inline js in Firebug but it never reaches there. No error. I assume there's something else I can do in Firebug to trace this?

Comment: could you show some code? your template, the header and footer files? otherwise we can only guess what's going wrong here.

Comment: @user1335657. It seems you aren't logged in as jchwebdev, which is why you can't edit 'your own' question. If you have lost your login details, try speaking to the team@stackoverflow to merge these accounts you have created.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this.](http://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/)

Did you have the proper header files?

Comment: I figured it out... well, sorta. This is one of those things where I knew I'd get the answer. Even if I was asking the wrong question! :D There was an error in one of my JS plug-ins. I think what was happening is that this caused jQuery1.7 to stop. For some reason, adding the jQuery1.3.2, the offending plug-in would carry on executing in 1.3.2! Which I had no idea was possible. Or at least, that's my -theory- since everything worked once I corrected the error and removed jQuery1.3.2.

Comment: BTW: The 'error' was that I was trying to call a function from a JS lib that was not included---I was lazy and left it in from another project. I had never thought of this as an 'error' because previously I had only used 1.3.2 and if I called a non-existent function jQuery seemed to just ignore it and keep going. Apparently 1.7 is more rigorous? Or is it something else? --JC

Comment: I wish I knew. The exact same error you describe cost me a lot of time on one of my projects. I was able to resolve it but I still haven't figured out the root cause!